# How can I achieve proper shadow rendering for rounded frameless windows on Linux?

Tags: window-management

Developing an application launcher I face shadow rendering issues. While macOS handles rounded windows with shadows seamlessly, on Linux, the shadows for such windows appear to support rectangular windows only. Is there a workaround or a specific approach to ensure that rounded frameless windows display correct shadows on Linux?

I tried to display a client side shadow but this ends up in a lot of work, like problems when maximized, uniform look etc. I'd prefer a proper system decoration solution.

Comment: What window manager are you using (and are you using compton/picom alongside it)? If your window isn't RGBA (with its own alpha), then it's the specific window manager that provides the shadows, and each has its own logic for dealing with that; e.g. I seem to remember older compton just outright didn't support non-rectangular shadows. Also, what UI toolkit are you using – does it perhaps have its own system that would deal with client-side shadows on your behalf (like GTK does)?

Comment: Yes indeed what window (compositing?) manager are you using. There are already existing projects dedicated to kwin you could probably get some inspiration from : https://sourceforge.net/projects/shapecorners/ or more cpu-hungry https://github.com/matinlotfali/KDE-Rounded-Corners?tab=readme-ov-file

Comment: Its a Qt app. It is not about the WM/compositor I am using. I am looking for a generic solution since the app should run on almost all desktops. Its a simple frameless (meaning no server side decoration) window with round corners. See the gallery [here](https://alternativeto.net/software/albert/about/).